# Magento 2 Grunt problems

Tags: gruntjs, magento2

I'm getting slightly confused with grunt and magento 2. Should I be using Grunt on the server or on my local machine? New to grunt so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Local machine**. You don't need to run it in production, because you should be running `setup:static-content:deploy` with the Magento CLI when deploying to production, which will compile all static content for you.

For development, Magento 2 provides a `Gruntfile.js.sample` and a `package.json.sample` for local development. You should rename them to `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json`, and then install the dependencies with `npm install`. As long as you have grunt installed, you should be able to then run the grunt commands to compile your code while you are developing. You can see more info and the grunt commands here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

You should also make sure that you are running your local development environment in "developer mode": http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html#change-to-developer-mode

Answer (score 0):

Grunt should be used locally and staging, whenever you have the application in developer mode. In production mode (live site) it shouldn't be used.